# Insert Trigger to a Linked Server error

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update, insert, delete

I created an insert trigger in a table that will fire when an insert/update/delete is made. The trigger is supposed to send information about the query that fired it, but every time it fires, the error below occurs.

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "TMP-DBA-DB" returned message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure AuditlDealerDebitAuditTrailTEST, Line 22
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "TMP-DBA-DB" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Here's my trigger query:

```
    create trigger dbo.AuditlDealerDebitAuditTrailTEST
on [dbo].[lDealerDebitAuditTrailTEST] 

after UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
as 

declare @TableName varchar(20), @User varchar(20), @PCNo varchar(20), @server nvarchar(30), @Database varchar(30), 
        @table varchar(30),@activity varchar(20), @date datetime;

begin
         set  @TableName = 'lDealerDebitAuditTrailTEST' 

if exists(SELECT * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted)
begin
    SET @User = SYSTEM_USER;
    set @PCNo = HOST_NAME();
    set @server = @@SERVERNAME;
    set @Database = DB_NAME();
    Set @table = @TableName;
    SET @activity = 'UPDATE';
    set @date = GETDATE();
      INSERT into [TMP-DBA-DB].[Josel_TestDB].[dbo].[audit](ExecutedBy,  PCNo, "Server", "Database", "Table", Activity, ExecutedOn)
         values (@User, @PCNo,  @server, @Database,  @table, @Activity, @date);
end

If exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
begin
    SET @Activity = 'INSERT';
    SET @User = SYSTEM_USER;
    set @PCNo = HOST_NAME();
    set @server = @@SERVERNAME;
    set @Database = DB_NAME();
    Set @table = @TableName;
    set @date = GETDATE();
     INSERT into [TMP-DBA-DB].[Josel_TestDB].dbo.audit(ExecutedBy,  PCNo, "Server", "Database", "Table", Activity, ExecutedOn)
         values (@User, @PCNo,  @server, @Database,  @table, @Activity, @date);
    end
If exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(Select * from inserted)
begin 
    SET @activity = 'DELETE';
    SET @User = SYSTEM_USER;
    set @PCNo = HOST_NAME();
    set @server = @@SERVERNAME;
    set @Database = DB_NAME();
    Set @table = @TableName;
    set @date = GETDATE();
     INSERT into [TMP-DBA-DB].[Josel_TestDB].dbo.audit(ExecutedBy,  PCNo, "Server", "Database", "Table", Activity, ExecutedOn)
         values (@User, @PCNo,  @server, @Database,  @table, @Activity, @date);
    end

    end
GO
```

Comment: Have you configured MSDTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting up the [distributor transaction coordinator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191440(v=sql.105))?

Distributed transactions are transactions that require SQL Server to get data from a source outside of the instance of SQL Server you are using (this most frequently entails the use of Linked Servers et al.

An example of a distributed transaction would be for example:

```
INSERT MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3....) 
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 ... FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 ...
FROM RemoteTable
WHERE predicate1 = Condition1')
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ColX = Col1
```

to set up the distributed transaction coordinator follow the steps below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you click apply, it will ask for restarting the service and you say `yes`.

this article is also worth reading:

[Do I need DTC for my SQL Server?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2010/10/18/do-i-need-dtc-for-my-sql-server/)

Comment: Do I need to do this to both of the servers?